# error connection to database c#

Tags: c#, database, azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to connect to a database from VS2017

```
 var str = str1.ConnectionString =
                "Data Source=141.*****.199;" +
                "Initial Catalog=****;" +
                "User id=***;" +
                "Password=****;";
                using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        var text = "SELECT * FROM Users u WHERE u.Id=76769";
                           ...
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, e.ToString());
                    }
```

and get error

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

It's azure function. If I set this connection from LogicApp, then there are no errors.
Why the connection does not work from the azure-function?

Comment: Are you allowed to connect to an external DB form Azure Functions?

Comment: In what environment is your Azure Function running? Public Azure? On-premises? in an ILB ASE? More information is required to help you with this question.

Answer (score 0):

can someone help. Functions refer to the database not with only ip , which are listed on the portal. They have several variants. And on the portal these addresses do not look, only through https: //resources.azure.com. And yes, you just need to specify in the firewall all valid values

Answer (score 0):

I am connecting to an SQL DB from Azure Function, and I noticed a little difference in connection string that I am using.

Pls try and see if it works for you:

```
"Server=tcp:141.*****.199,1433;Initial Catalog=****;User ID=*****;Password=*****;"
```

- 1433 - is the default MS SQL port number.